# Как преобразовать массив байтов в строку и в дату с временем

Tags: c#

Как преобразовать массив байтов в строку. Допустим есть массив байтов - "c7e0f8f3ecebe5ededeef1f2fc20f1e8". Если перевести в строку должно получиться - "Зашумленность си". Кодировка здесь вроде бы - windows 1251.  И еще нужно преобразовать массив  типа "15 d8 62 0a 71 9d e4 40" в дату и время.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> Split(string s, int size) {
    var sr = new StringReader(s);
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) {
        var buffer = new char[size];
        var c = sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, size);
        yield return new String(buffer);
    }
}

var s = "c7e0f8f3ecebe5ededeef1f2fc20f1e8";
var bytes = Split(s, 2).Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16));
var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```

результат

```
"Зашумленность си"
```

Answer (score 0):

это что касается строчки

```
var stringResult = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetString(byteArray);
```

а это получение даты

```
var lDate = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray, 0);
var dateTimeResult = new DateTime(1980,1,1).AddMilliseconds(lDate);
```